# Custom shortcuts (gnome/kde/linux styled) in osx

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, kde

I have recently changed jobs and they gave me a MacBook to work with. The problem is that I have zero experience with this OS (I have used different linux boxes since I can recall) and I cannot get used to how the system behaved and my usual keyboard shortcuts to manage windows (like maximizing to the left, or right, or general), the different workspaces or how to launch apps with just my preffered combination of keystrokes. 80% of my time is linux terminal and the other 20% is web browser.

Do you know any good resource (blog, page or something) or tip on how to configure osx to adapt to me and behave as I expect?

Comment: Give up now. Learn the new paradigm. It is a) impossible to do completely & b) will confuse the heck out of you if you have to use someone else's Mac. Give it two months, you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a GitHub page where someone has remapped their Mac to linux keybindings using Mac's "DefaultKeyBinding.dict" feature.

[GitHub Project providing linux key bindings for the Mac operating system.](https://gist.github.com/lenalebt/64d5ea94d6077a5becd00c33d0514cac)

This should provide a quick solution to your problem.

In case you want more information about the main tool they used to achieve this or some other helpful tools, I will provide some details. The main tool used is Mac's "DefaultKeyBinding.dict" feature. It provides very robust and efficient control over key bindings.

For some reason it is very hard to find information on this topic. Here are links to Apple's documentation on this feature:

[Apple Documentation for custom keyboard bindings.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html)

There is also an extremely helpful guide by on the Harvard website detailing the Cocoa text system (this "DefaultKeyBinding.dict" feature being one of the things they cover). This is by far the best resource I have found on customizing Mac key bindings.

[Harvard Computer Science department in depth explanation of the Cocoa text system.](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html)

Many other tools offer key binding customization for Macs with user-friendly interfaces, and each have their benefits and drawbacks. A few examples are Keyboard Maestro and Karabiner-Elements.